# Google Analytics 4 API missing location dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

It looks like the Google Analytics 4 API is missing the `location` dimension [for real time metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/realtime-api-schema).

Is there a way to get latitude and longitude data using this API? Are there plans to include this dimension before the Universal Analytics shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

The Google analytics api's for Ga4 are still in beta. The team is adding new dimensions and metrics every now and then.

Currently there is no location dimension and the team has not said wither or not it will be added.  We just have to wait and see.